# Multi ListBox .net dual

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, controls, listbox

Any suggestions on a .net multi dual listbox?

Saw this control http://ajaxlistbox.codeplex.com/ seems to be pretty sweet. 
just want to know any suggestions.

Comment: Why can't you use the one linked to?

Comment: Just trying to see other's opinions or anything better out there

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Dual Listbox jQuery plugin](http://www.meadmiracle.com/dlb/DLBDocumentation.aspx).  Has pretty good reviews, you'd just have to hook it into data from a server side control.